# How do I filter my results when scraping a website using Nokogiri gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri

I am trying to scrape list of restaurants for my zip code from Deliveroo.co.uk

I need to add a way to figure out whether a restaurant is open or closed... from the website its very clear, but I just need to update my code to reflect this.

How do I go about doing this? I need to create something like a 'status' variable and then set each restaurant to 'open' or 'closed'.

Here is the website I'm trying to scrape from: https://deliveroo.co.uk/restaurants/london/maida-vale?postcode=W92DE&time=1800&day=today

And my code is below.

thanks.

```
    require 'open-uri'
    require 'nokogiri'
    require 'csv'

    # Store URL to be scraped
   url = "https://deliveroo.co.uk/restaurants/london/maida-vale?postcode=W92DE"

    # Parse the page with Nokogiri
    page = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))

    # Display output onto the screen
    name =[]
    page.css('span.list-item-title.restaurant-name').each do |line|
     name << line.text
    end

   category = []
   page.css('span.restaurant-detail.detail-cat').each do |line|
    category << line.text
   end

   delivery_time = []
   page.css('span.restaurant-detail.detail-time').each do |line|
     delivery_time << line.text
   end

  distance = []
  page.css('span.restaurant-detail.detail-distance').each do |line|
   distance << line.text
  end

  status = []

  # Write data to CSV file
  CSV.open("deliveroo.csv", "w") do |file|
  file << ["Name", "Category", "Delivery Time", "Distance", "Status"]
  name.length.times do |i|
  file << [name[i], category[i], delivery_time[i], distance[i]]
  end
  end
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to check `li.restaurant--details` have / have not class `unavailable` for close / open restaurant.

```
status = []
page.css('li.restaurant--details').each do |line|
  if line.attr("class").include? "unavailable"
    sts = "closed"
  else
    sts = "open"
  end
  status << sts
end
```

Btw, you should remove white space when get restaurant_name, etc ...

```
page.css('span.list-item-title.restaurant-name').each do |line|
 name << line.text.strip
end
```

You can refer my code at here: https://gist.github.com/vinhnglx/4eaeb2e8511dd1454f42